# Use of parametrised constructor is giving error

Tags: c++

I've been trying to learn about parametrised constructors:

Here is the program I wrote:

```
#include <iostream> //Using a parametrised constructor i.e. we give an integer value as a parameter
using namespace std;
class item{
    int cost;
    int price;
    public:
    item (int a){
    cost=a;
    }
    void display(){ //Display is not a constructor, hence we need to  specify its return type and parameters
        cout << cost;
    }
} item1;
int main(){
    item1(5);
    item1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get an error on Visual Studio Code:

```
call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of class creation you are asking to create an object named item1 but you are not providing any value, that's why it is throwing error you cannot create an object without '('.

After object creation you can't call the constructor. you can access all the methods and fields.

```
#include <iostream> //Using a parametrised constructor i.e. we give an integer value as a parameter
using namespace std;
class item{
    int cost;
    int price;
    public:
    item (int a){
    cost=a;
    }
    void display(){ //Display is not a constructor, hence we need to  specify its return type and parameters
        cout << cost;
    }
} item1(5);

int main(){
    item1.display();
    return 0;
}
```